# Can connect to port 80 only in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I started an EC2 instance and am trying to listen to different ports now.

But I can connect only through port 80, ie., i can access the server through the elastic IP, telnet ONLY to port 80. Telnet to any other port fails.

I have the same configuration for all ports on the security gateway.

[image]

I even have the Network ACL configured with similar rules. What is wrong and how do I fix it ?

Note: I do not have enough points to attach more than one link.

Comment: Is anything *running* on the ports you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @ceejayoz: I have set up a node server that is listening on port 9000. That is also the application I am trying to access.

Comment: Should I kill all process, run my node application again and try connecting to port 9000 ?

Comment: I'd check with one of the techniques at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/ that your app is actually listening on that port.

Comment: @ceejayoz I updated the post with the result of netstat command. I am using windows.

Comment: I believe `TIME_WAIT` means your Node app closed its connection. Can't speak to why without the code, but it's not running right. You can probably confirm this by trying to telnet locally on the server itself, which'd rule out any AWS networking issues.

Comment: I checked with netstat -a -b which shows clearly that node.exe is listening on privateIP:9000. Also, despite TIME_WAIT, the application is still accessible on the browser with privateIP:9000. So that means the connection is not closed.

Comment: What do your _Security group_ rules assigned to that instance look like?

Comment: @msanford : I update the post with a picture of my Security Group permissions

Answer (score -1):

What services are you trying to access, on which ports? Why are you using telnet to port 80? Port 80 is http. http and RDP appear to be responding.

There are many, many resources that describe how to connect to your ec2 instance. Can you go through the efforts you've tried?

Your instances does appear to be open to the world on a wide variety of ports according to security groups. I'd delete your ACLs as that's most likely to be a problem based on what limited information we have.

If you post the IP maybe we can test it.

Can you connect to port 9000 when you RDP in?

Comment: I have a node server listening on port 9000 and this is the application I am trying to access. My ssh and/or telnet request times out. I cannot connect. But telnet request specifying port 80, seems to make a connection. I just used it to check. I used the following command to connect through: ssh -vvv  xxx.pem administrator@publicDNS

Comment: the elastic IP is 52.27.160.173

Comment: I deleted all the ACL rules I added. It has a default rule 100, allowing all traffic from all sources and another rule * denying all traffic from all sources. The problem does not go away though

Comment: Ok since it's a windows server my SSH comments don't apply. I guess you need to open RDP or similar. HTTP and RDP seem to work fine. So I guess the problem is most likely that you have your listening application set up wrong. Can you connect to it locally with telnet, when you RDP into the machine?

Comment: Any chance Windows local firewall is blocking the traffic? Also beware that AWS VPC network ACLs are stateless so if you use them, be sure to allow return traffic as well.

Comment: @jukka: I have disabled firewall on my local system. Following what Tim suggested, i deleted all entries I made with ACL. So they only have the default rule 100 and * to allow and deny all traffic.